# MySQL bitwise operations

Tags: mysql, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am trying to understand bitwise operators in MySQL.

I have:

```
SELECT 1 & 51 FROM bits = 1
SELECT 2 & 51 FROM bits = 2
SELECT 3 & 51 FROM bits = 3
SELECT 4 & 51 FROM bits = 0
SELECT 5 & 51 FROM bits = 1
SELECT 6 & 51 FROM bits = 2
```

With `SELECT 1 & 51 FROM bits` is this asking that the first bit (1) is present in both 1 and 51, if it is then I understand this.

But `SELECT 6 & 51 FROM bits = 2` doesn't make sense to me as the 6th bit would be 32(?) which isn't is 6, as 6 is made from the 2nd and 4th bit(?), but 32 is present in 51.

So I am a bit confused as to how this works, could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two arguments aren't the indexes of the bits - it means you represent each number in binary, and perform the operation between each bit independently.

```
 6 in binary: 000110
51 in binary: 110011
AND           ======
              000010
```

The result, `000010`, is the binary representation of 2.

(Note the the preceeding zeros were truncated for clarity's sake)

Comment: So it's saying that the bit "2" is present in both 6 and 51, even though 4 is not?

Comment: Yes. 6=4+2; 51=32+16+2+1

Comment: So 4 & 51 is 0 because 4: 000100 and 51: 110011, and the bit in 4 isn't used in 51?

Comment: @imperium2335 yes, exactly.

Comment: So 4 | 51 would return 4 because 000100 is in 4?

Comment: @imperium2335 yup, indeed

Comment: @imperium2335 oh, no, wait a sec. I misread - that's an `|`, not an `&. `|` will set a bit to be 1 if either corresponding bit is 1, so indeed, the result would be 55. 4 % 51 will be 0, since 51 doesn't have the 4 bit as 1.

Comment: So 4 | 51 is turning on the 4th bit in 51 becoming 110111? 4 | 55 is still 55 because the 4th bit is already active (it doesn't simply toggle the bit?)

Comment: @imperium2335 yup. `|` is about toggling, it's about "is the bit 1 in **at least one** of the arguments". `&` is about "is the bit 1 in **both** arguments".

Comment: Thanks :D I will need to practice to get it drilled into my head.

Answer (score 0):

"6" doesn't refer to the sixth bit.  It refers to the binary value.  With 8 bits:   00000110.

If you want the sixth bit, use either 1<<6 or 32.

Comment: So Mysql goes right to left and not left to right like PHP?

Comment: @imperium2335 . . . The documentation describes "1 << 2" as 4.  I don't know how PHP defines this construct, but this does but the low-order bits on the right.